# Jenkins SCM plugin, how do I get a list of every updated file since last build?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline build and I want to iterate over all of the files that were updated since the last build. I looked around and thought the changeSets variable of the current build object might work.  so I tried this:

```
def gitUrl = "git@gitlab.xxx.com:me/myrepo.git"
def gitResponse = dir(".") { checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: gitUrl,credentialsId:'xxxkey']]
]) }
// don't do anything if nothing changed
if(gitResponse.GIT_COMMIT == gitResponse.GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT) {
  echo "No changes detected."
  return
}
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
  def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
  for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
    def entry = entries[j]
    echo "Change detected: ${entry}"
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList
```

Any way to list out each changed file since the last build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created scripted pipeline that prints changes introduced in current build:

```
node {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'YOUR_BRANCH']],
     userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'YOUR_GIT_URL']]])      
    stage('TEST') {
        def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
          def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
          for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            entry.getAffectedPaths().each {
                echo "Change detected: ${it}"   
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To paraphrase Krzysztof's answer in a more functional way, you can get the set of modified paths as follows:

```
def paths = currentBuild
  .changeSets.collectMany {
    it.items.collectMany {
      it.affectedPaths
    }
  }.unique()
```

You can check it then with `echo paths.join('\n')`. You can use it in a declarative pipeline inside of a `script` step.